# Ask about Create Checkbox with Pagination and Hook in Reactjs

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have code below:

```
const UrlNews = props => {
 const { rootState, dispatch } = React.useContext(Store);
 const { listUrlNew, hasChange } = rootState.urlNew;
 const history = useHistory();
 const location = useLocation();

 const [page, setPage] = useState(1);
 const [pageSize, setPageSize] = useState(20);
 const [query, setQuery] = useState('');
 const [openConfirmDeleteModal, setOpenConfirmDeleteModal] = useState(false);
 const [idWantDelete, setIdWantDelete] = useState('');
 const [confirmDelMessage, setConfirmDelMessage] = useState('');
 const [inputList, setInputList] = useState([]);
 const [total, setTotal] = useState(0);
 const [changeCheckBox, setChangeCheckBox] = useState(false);

   React.useEffect(() => {
    let data = null;
    if (listUrlNew != null) {
        data = listUrlNew.data;
        if (data !== undefined) {
            data.sort((a, b) => (b.addedAtUtc > a.addedAtUtc) ? 1 : -1);

            if (changeCheckBox === false) {
                data.map((item, i) => item.checked = false);
                setInputList(data);

            }
        }

        setTotal(listUrlNew.totalRecords === undefined
            ? 0
            : listUrlNew.totalRecords);
     }
  })
  React.useEffect(() => {
    if (hasChange === true) {
        hasChangeUrlNewAction(false, dispatch);
    }

    var model = {
        Keyword: query,
        //   doc: '',
        PageIndex: page,
        PageSize: pageSize,
    };

    const paramUrl = new URLSearchParams(location.search.substring(1));
    if (
        paramUrl.get('PageIndex') != null &&
        paramUrl.get('PageIndex') !== page
    ) {
        setPage(parseInt(paramUrl.get('PageIndex')));
        model.PageIndex = parseInt(paramUrl.get('PageIndex'));
    }
    if (
        paramUrl.get('PageSize') != null &&
        paramUrl.get('PageSize') !== pageSize
    ) {
        setPageSize(parseInt(paramUrl.get('PageSize')));
        model.PageSize = parseInt(paramUrl.get('PageSize'));
    }
    // if (paramUrl.get('status') != null && paramUrl.get('status') !== status) {
    //   setStatus(paramUrl.get('status'));
    //   model.status = parseInt(paramUrl.get('status'));
    // }
    if (paramUrl.get('Keyword') != null && paramUrl.get('Keyword') !== query) {
        setQuery(paramUrl.get('Keyword'));
        model.Keyword = paramUrl.get('Keyword').toString();
    }

    getAllUrlNewAction(model, dispatch);
    history.replace(
        createUrlWithParam(URL_NEW_PATH, {
            status: model.status,
            PageIndex: model.PageIndex,
            PageSize: model.PageSize,
            Keyword: model.Keyword,
        }),
    );
   }, [hasChange]);

   const reloadPage = (page, pageSize, query) => {
    history.replace(
        createUrlWithParam(URL_NEW_PATH, {
            PageIndex: page,
            PageSize: pageSize,
            Keyword: query,
        }),
    );
    window.location.reload(true);
  };

   const onChangeType = e => {
    reloadPage(page, pageSize, e.target.value, query);
   };

   const onChangeShowNumber = e => {
    reloadPage(page, parseInt(e.target.value), query);
   };

   const changePage = number => {
    reloadPage(number, pageSize, query);
   };

    const deletePost = (id, name) => {
    setIdWantDelete(id);
    setConfirmDelMessage(name);
    setOpenConfirmDeleteModal(true);
   };

  const acceptDelete = () => {
    if (idWantDelete !== '') {
        deleteUrlNewAction(idWantDelete, dispatch);
        setOpenConfirmDeleteModal(false);
    }
  };

   const cancelDelete = () => {
    setIdWantDelete(0);
    setOpenConfirmDeleteModal(false);
  };

   const handleListUrlNew = (e, itemPost, index) => {
    const list = [...inputList];
    list[index]["checked"] = e;
    setChangeCheckBox(true);
    setInputList(list);
   };

   return (
    <Page
        title="Tin mới"
        breadcrumbs={[{ name: 'Tin mới', active: true }]}
    >
        <Row>
            <Col>
                <Card className="mb-3">
                    <CardHeader className="d-flex justify-content-between">

                        <Form inline>
                            <Label for="exampleEmail2">Hiển thị :</Label>
                            <select
                                className="form-control"
                                value={pageSize}
                                onChange={e => onChangeShowNumber(e)}
                            >
                                {objectShowNumber.map((item, index) => (
                                    <option key={index} value={item.value}>
                                        {item.text}
                                    </option>
                                ))}
                            </select>
                        </Form>
                        <NavLink
                            href={createUrlWithParam("")}
                            className="nav-link-reject"
                        >
                            <Button color="info">Thêm mới</Button>
                        </NavLink>
                    </CardHeader>
                    <CardBody>
                        <Table responsive>
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>STT</th>
                                    <th>Tiêu đề</th>
                                    <th>Đường link gốc</th>
                                    <th>Phân loại</th>
                                    <th>Nguồn</th>
                                    <th>Thời gian tạo</th>
                                    <th>H.động</th>
                                    <th>Check</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            {inputList!= null && inputList!== undefined && inputList.length > 0 ? (
                                <tbody>
                                    {inputList.map((itemPosts, i) => (
                                        <tr key={i} role="row" className="odd">
                                            <td className="mgl10">
                                                {i + 1 + (page - 1) * pageSize}
                                            </td>
                                            <td className="sorting_1" title={itemPosts.url} >
                                                {subInput(itemPosts.title, 100)}
                                            </td>
                                            <td className="sorting_1">
                                                {subInput(itemPosts.baseUrl, 100)}
                                            </td>
                                            <td className="sorting_1">
                                                {subInput(itemPosts.category === null ? "" : 
       itemPosts.category, 100)}
                                            </td>
                                            <td className="sorting_1">
                                                {subInput(itemPosts.fromWhichSource, 100)}
                                            </td>
                                            <td className="sorting_1">
                                                {subInput(
                                                    
       formatDateTimeVibizCrawler(itemPosts.addedAtUtc),
                                                    100,
                                                )}
                                            </td>
                                            <td>
                                                <Nav>
                                                    <NavItem>
                                                        <NavLink
                                                            onClick={() =>
                                                                deletePost(itemPosts.id, 
     itemPosts.name)
                                                            }
                                                        >
                                                            <MdDeleteForever
                                                                title="Xóa"
                                                                className="table-action- 
     control"
                                                            />
                                                        </NavLink>
                                                    </NavItem>
                                                </Nav>
                                            </td>
                                            <td>
                                                <FormInput
                                                    Type="checkbox"
                                                    Value={itemPosts.checked}
                                                    handleOnChange={e => handleListUrlNew(e, 
      itemPosts)}
                                                />
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                    ))}
                                </tbody>
                            ) : (
                                <tbody>
                                    <tr className="txt-center">
                                        <td colSpan="12">Không có dữ liệu</td>
                                    </tr>
                                </tbody>
                            )}
                        </Table>
                        <ConfirmModal
                            isOpen={openConfirmDeleteModal}
                            confirmType="delete"
                            handleAccept={() => acceptDelete()}
                            handleCancel={() => cancelDelete()}
                            content={confirmDelMessage}
                        />
                    </CardBody>
                </Card>
                <div className="col-sm-12">
                    <Pagination
                        itemClass="page-item"
                        linkClass="page-link"
                        innerClass="pagination pagination-sm no-margin pull-right"
                        activePage={page}
                        itemsCountPerPage={pageSize}
                        totalItemsCount={total}
                        pageRangeDisplayed={5}
                        onChange={number => changePage(number)}
                    />
                </div>
            </Col>
        </Row>
    </Page>
  );
};
```

How am I going to make checkbox with pagination? Because when I check an item in first page then jump into next page, then turn back to previous page, the checkbox always lost. I have an idea of saving the list into local storage but I dont know if it is the best solution.

Can someone give me some instructions? Thank you very much!!!!

Comment: You are already using context api , why don't you save all the state in there ?

Comment: you mean save in the Store (rootState)? It is not possible because when you change page which mean reload, the state will also refresh